# What is viewchild ElementRef in angular

Tags: angular

Hi I am new to AngularJs, recently we I review some angular codes, I saw like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Network, DataSet } from 'vis';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: '<div #network></div>'
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('network', {static: false}) el: ElementRef;
  private networkInstance: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     const container = this.el.nativeElement;
     const nodes = new DataSet<any>([
        {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
        {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
        {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
        {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
    ]);

    const edges = new DataSet<any>([
        {from: 1, to: 3},
        {from: 1, to: 2},
        {from: 2, to: 4},
        {from: 2, to: 5}
    ]);
    const data = { nodes, edges };

    this.networkInstance = new Network(container, data, {});
  }
}
```

the reference is : [How to make Network visualization work in vis.js with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418587/how-to-make-network-visualization-work-in-vis-js-with-angular)

So I am confused what is **@ViewChild('network', {static: false}) el: ElementRef;** For my understanding, viewchild usually used for parent component to call children components. but in this example, I tried to run the code, it works with no  child component defined. So here the ElementRef is the "child"?

Answer (score 4):

ViewChild here lets you add a reference to an html element in the same component
In your case the div with #network
It's similar to document.getElementById except it only detects a 'child' in the same component

Comment: what if we want  document.getElementByName? not document.getElementById. are they same in viewchild

Answer (score 1):

ViewChild is often used to refer to child components. It can also be used to refer to HTML Elements in your template. ElementRef is a way for angular to wrap HTML Elements and manipulate them programmatically. In your example, the <div> is assigned a template variable #network, which is used as a selector to capture that particular <div> in the Component's el property. When you remove the template, the selector returns no Elements, and thus el remains undefined.